# Insert or delete a timestamp based on cell value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, timestamp

With this script I can create automatically a timestamp in col G based on "SI" in col E.
Now I would that:
1 - When I delete an existing value "SI" in col E, the timestamp must be deleted
2 - And so, if I put a different value from "SI" in col E, the timestamp must be deleted
How could I proceed?

```
function onEdit(e){
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  if( s.getName() == "STAMPA2" )
  if(e.range.columnStart == 5 && e.value === 'SI'){
     e.range.offset(0,2).setValue(new Date());
  }
}
```

UPDATE:
Based on the answer of Cooper and Tanaike, I have edited the script, with this one, but the problem is that when a select "URGENTE" in col G the value in col E become "URGENTE", but if I change the value in col G with "SI" the date format is only dd/mm/yyyy and not dd/mm/yyyy - HH:MM (that I need).
How to solve?

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var s = e.range.getSheet();
  if (s.getName() == "STAMPA2" && e.range.columnStart == 5) {
    if (e.value == 'SI') {
      e.range.offset(0, 3).setValue(new Date());
    } else {
      e.range.offset(0, 3).setValue('');
    }
    if (e.value == 'URGENTE') {
      e.range.offset(0, 3).setValue('URGENTE');
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- When the value of `SI` is put to the column "E", you want to put the current date to the column "G".
- When the value of `SI` is not put to the column "E", you want to delete the value of the column "G".

In this case, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  var { range, value } = e;
  var s = range.getSheet();
  if (s.getName() == "STAMPA2" && range.columnStart == 5) {
    range.offset(0, 2).setValue(value === 'SI' ? new Date() : "");
  }
}
```

or

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  var { range } = e;
  var s = range.getSheet();
  if (s.getName() == "STAMPA2" && range.columnStart == 5) {
    range.offset(0, 2).setValue(range.getValue() === 'SI' ? new Date() : "");
  }
}
```

### Added:

For your updated question, how about the following sample script?

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  var { range, value } = e;
  var s = range.getSheet();
  if (s.getName() == "STAMPA2" && range.columnStart == 5) {
    var r = range.offset(0, 2);
    if (value == 'SI') {
      r.setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat('dd"/"MM"/"yyyy" "HH":"mm');
    } else if (value == 'URGENTE') {
      r.setValue('URGENTE');
    } else {
      r.clearContent();
    }
  }
}
```

- In this sample, the date object is put as the date format of `dd"/"MM"/"yyyy" "HH":"mm`.
- If you want to put the date as the string, you can also use `r.setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"))` instead of `r.setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat('dd"/"MM"/"yyyy" "HH":"mm')`.

Comment: I have update the question, please see on top.

Comment: @Gavis Thank you for replying. About your updated question, I added one more sample script. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your updated question and that was not useful, I apologize.

Comment: Perfect! It works good

Comment: @Gavis Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved.